# Abbreviate Number Function Won't Output Negative Value

Tags: php, preg-replace

So I have this class, which appreciates numbers. For example, `AbbreviateNum::convert(1178);` will round up and turn it into `1.18K`.

This works as it should, nicely. However, I can't seem to figure out how to output negative numbers. If I run `AbbreviateNum::convert(-1178);`, it will output the same response `1.18K`. Without the negative indicator.

Any tips on how I fix this?

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class AbbreviateNum
{

    /**
     * Abbreviate long numbers
     * 
     * @return Response
     */
    public static function convert($num)
    {
        $num = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $num);
        $sizes = array("", "K", "M");

        if ($num == 0) return(0); 
        else return (round($num/pow(1000, ($i = floor(log($num, 1000)))), 2) . $sizes[$i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your regex removes the sign... (and also any decimal point)

Comment: Why not calculate it from the absolute value of the input and then if the original input is less than 0, return `0 - $output`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the modified function that provides a little bit more robustness for the strings it will accept.

```
public static function convert($num)
{
    $num = intval(preg_replace('/[^\-\.0-9]/', '', $num));
    $sizes = array("", "K", "M");

    if ($num == 0) return(0); 
    else return (round($num/pow(1000, ($i = floor(log(abs($num), 1000)))), 2) . $sizes[abs($i)]);
}
```

Comment: I see what you did here - very nice!

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the name of the `convert` Method's argument (`num`) & do a simple `strstr()` Check for "-". If found, prefix you result with "-" like this:

```
    <?php   

        namespace App\Helpers;

        class AbbreviateNum
        {

            /**
             * Abbreviate long numbers
             *
             * @return Response
             */
            public static function convert($givenNumber){
                $num    = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $givenNumber);
                $sizes = array("", "K", "M");

                if ($num == 0) {
                    return(0);
                }else {
                    $number =  (round($num/pow(1000, ($i = floor(log($num, 1000)))), 2) . $sizes[$i]);
                    if(strstr($givenNumber, "-")){
                        $number = "-" . $number;
                    }
                    return $number;
                }
            }

        }

        var_dump(AbbreviateNum::convert(-1785));
       // PRODUCES:   string '-1.79K' (length=6)

        var_dump(AbbreviateNum::convert(1785));
       // PRODUCES:   string '1.79K' (length=5)
```

Confirm it [HERE](https://eval.in/606108).

Hope this helps a bit...

Cheers & Good Luck ;-)

Comment: This works well, thank you. But @cmorrissey provided a slightly cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

For such conversion, I'd use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function:

```
public static function convert($num) {
    $sizes = array("", "K", "M", "G", "T");
    $i = 0;
    $res = $num;
    while (abs($num) > 1000) {$num /= 1000; $i++; $res = sprintf("%.2f$sizes[$i]", $num);}
    return $res;
}
```